# What is wrong with this code, lots of help needed?

Tags: python

```
welcome = raw_input("Enter username:")
print "Welcome to dungeon crawler, %s" % (welcome)
items = []
starting_item_var = True

def sec_1():
    while True:
        starting_item = raw_input("Hammer or sword (use no caps!)")
        if starting_item == "hammer":
          items.append("hammer")
          print "Hammer was added to items"
        if starting_item == "sword":
          items.append("sword")
          print "Sword was added to items"
        if starting_item != "sword" or "hammer":
          print "Invalid option"
          continue
        return


sec_1()
```

In the code here, I am asking the person to pick a starting item to use. It will .append the item to a items list. If the item is not a sword or hammer, it is supposed to say invalid option and send you back to the beggining of the function. Unforunately, it will .append either the sword or hammer to the list, but it will run the third 'if' statement anyway.

Comment: > (use no caps!) < Do not tell your user what to do, just call `starting_item.lower()` afterwards

Comment: `or "hammer"` is *always* `True`. This is not English, you want to test whether *`starting_item` isn't "sword" and `starting_item` isn't "hammer"*. Or you want a simpler `if..elif..else` chain.

Answer (score 2):

The English language "X is not Y or Z" does not translate exactly like that to Python. In Python, `X != Y or Z` is treated as `(X != Y) or (Z)`; `Z` is its own condition, and since `"hammer"` by itself is always true, `or "hammer"` makes any condition true. You really want to say `starting_item != "sword" and starting_item != "hammer"`.

But really, you should not repeat your conditions at all:

```
if starting_item == "hammer":
    items.append("hammer")
    print "Hammer was added to items"
elif starting_item == "sword":
    items.append("sword")
    print "Sword was added to items"
else:
    print "Invalid option"
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your conditional for your third if

Change it to:

```
if starting_item != "sword" or starting_item !="hammer":
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following code

```
if starting_item not in ["sword", "hammer"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

`starting_item` can only have one value, so it is appropriate to use `elif` here. Also, it's a little cleaner to use `break` to exit the loop, in case you decide to add more code after the loop in the same function.

```
def sec_1():
    while True:
        starting_item = raw_input("Hammer or sword (use no caps!)")
        if starting_item == "hammer":
            items.append("hammer")
            print "Hammer was added to items"
        elif starting_item == "sword":
            items.append("sword")
            print "Sword was added to items"
        else:
            print "Invalid option"
            continue
        break
```

Finally, use a consistent amount of whitespace for each level of indentation.